# В адресной строке квадратные скобки пишутся вот таком виде "%5B%5D"

Tags: html, get, html-form

Добрый день.

Есть форма с чекбоксами, метод передачи GET (часть html кода):

```
....
<input type="checkbox" name="serv[]" value="1"> Сервер 1
<input type="checkbox" name="serv[]" value="2"> Сервер 2
<input type="checkbox" name="serv[]" value="3"> Сервер 3
<input type="checkbox" name="serv[]" value="4"> Сервер 4
....
```

Если в браузере (хроме) заполнить поля и отметить, допустим, первый чекбокс, нажать кнопку "отправить", то в адресной строке появиться вот такая запись:

mysite.ru/?serv%5B%5D=1

%5B%5D - это ANSII код (если я не ошибся) символов "[]".

В ФФ все нормально, ИЕ, Хром и Старая опера - %5B%5D  (в новой не смотрел).
На странице установлено:

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```

В htaccess установлено (я думаю, что это не важно):

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
```

**Вопрос**

Как, не меняя логики формы, отобразить в адресной строке не `mysite.ru/?serv%5B%5D=1`, а `mysite.ru/?serv[]=1`.

*Большое спасибо за ответы.*

(Добавлено)

> никак, ваши формы работают корректно, именно так как и должны работать.

Спасибо за ответ!
Но, как тогда получилось вот тут:

```
 rst.ua/oldcars/alfaromeo/?year[]=0&year[]=0&price[]=0&price[]=0&engine[]=0&engine[]=0&gear=0&fuel=0&drive=0&condition=0&model[]=11&model[]=15&model[2]=20&from=sform
```

Comment: То, что фф отображает не кодированные символы - исключительно его прихоть.

Answer (score 8):

> %5B%5D - это ANSII код (если я не ошибся) символов "[]".

нет, это не анси) и даже не ASCII, это урлкодированная строка

> ?serv%5B%5D=1

Это, абсолютно правильная урлкодированная строка

> Как, не меняя логики формы, отобразить в адресной строке не mysite.ru/?serv%5B%5D=1, а mysite.ru/?serv[]=1

никак, ваши формы работают корректно, именно так как и должны работать.

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL

Прочтите раздел "Кодирование URL"